# react-redux: getState() from any container

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have the following in App.js. For debugging purposes, I can `console.log` the current state with `store.getState()`.

```
const App = () => {
  const store = createStore(reducers);
  console.log(store.getState());
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router />
    </Provider>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Now how can I console.log `store.getState()` from containers within this app.

Update:
Following the 'connect' suggestion in the comments, this is a bottom part of the code in a container:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  Decrease,
  Increase,
  selectNumber
})(TableGenerator);
```

Where would I add the `getState()`?

Comment: there is the `connect` helper from 'react-redux', have you tried it?

Comment: Just a general tip: The redux dev tools for chrome are really quite nice. You can see the state tree in a nice graphical representation. Then, a simple `debugger` at any point in your code would do the trick.

Comment: I have updated the question. Do Redux dev tools work with react-native (debugging remotely in Chrome)? I have Redux Dev Tools installed but frankly not sure how to use them with React-native

Comment: Ok. I got the devtools working after installing remote-redux-devtools

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`mapStateToProps` first argument is actually the Redux state. It is practically an abstracted `getState()`.

```
const mapStateToProps = function(state, ownProps) {
   // state is equivalent to store.getState()
   // you then get the slice of data you need from the redux store
   // and pass it as props to your component

   return {
     someData: state.someData
   }
}
```